# MISRA QACPP level 3 warning - Expression(s) with floating point type used as operand(s) to +=

Tags: c++, misra

I have code which has lot of floating point arithmetic, for example:

```
float32_value1 += float32_value2
```

This results in MISRA QACPP level 3 warning -
Expression(s) with floating point type used as operand(s) to +=

Is there any workaround to resolve this warning other than suppressing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as the variable isn't a loop iterator, there's no MISRA rule against this code. What's the context, how is the variable used?

Comment: I see no obvious problem... I agree with @Lundin - we need a bit more detail.

Comment: There are no loops used. The function only has multiple such assignments. I agree with @Richard Corden 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The MISRA rule in question is categorised as "Document".  Rules in this category cannot be checked by analysis of the source code alone.

In this specific case the rule requires evidence that:

- use of floating-point is the only option,
- the team has the necessary knowledge,
- an appropriate process is being followed

This information is not evident from the written source, however, adding a suppression with a reference to where that evidence exists is a possible approach to cover "Document" rules.